# Is it possible to return mutiple values with @depends?

Tags: phpunit

The [@depends](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.depends) annotation allows to express dependencies between tests:

```php
class MyTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testOne()
    {
        // ...

        return $client;
    }

    /**
     * @depends testOne
     */
    public function testTwo(Client $client)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If I want to return several values, I can return an array of values, such as:

```php
class MyTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testOne()
    {
        // ...

        return array($client, $node);
    }

    /**
     * @depends testOne
     */
    public function testTwo(array $items)
    {
        list ($client, $node) = $items;

        // ...
    }
}
```

While it works fine, the problem with this approach is that I lose the type hinting of my IDE, and would have to manually annotate the `$client` and `$node` variables so that it understands them properly.

What I'd like to do instead, is to explicitly use the return values as separate parameters in the second test:

```php
class MyTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testOne()
    {
        // ...

        return array($client, $node);
    }

    /**
     * @depends testOne
     */
    public function testTwo(Client $client, Node $node)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked a while back and I think the answer is no. This is more of a clarity problem than anything. Because PHP only allows you to return one variable, you would need to introduce extra annotations logic at the PHPUnit level to tell it that what you are returning is not one  value but an array of values.

On a side note I have found that returning objects with @depends can get tricky. If for example you had two tests that both depends on sets say `@depends createUser`. The result is a reference. Then `testOne` changes the user object it is given because it's a reference `testTwo` will now get a user object that has been changed.

I originally thought the idea of @depends returning values was awesome, but in practice I've stopped using it.

Comment: Look like you're right, I've not found a solution myself since I asked the question. I've now managed to pass only one parameter to the next test with `@depends`, and take care not to have more than one test depending on a given test, to avoid the reference problem you mention!

Comment: `@depends` is definitely a lifesaver though: I'm doing functional tests with a virtual browser, and pass the browser from test to test, each loading one page, and the next test is passed a reference to the browser on the expected page. If a test fails, all the subsequent ones that depend on it are skipped!

Comment: I 100% agree, I love @depends. It's only the value passing I've stopped using.